# Qt, pass data to another class

Tags: c++, qt, qchart

I want to pass int testing to dialog.cpp when a push button is clicked from the mainwindow.cpp.

I got an error message as follows: "missing default argument on parameter testing"

What did I do wrong?

dialog.h

```
#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr, const int & testing);
    ~Dialog();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};
```

dialog.cpp

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent, const int & testing) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{   
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
dialog = new Dialog(this, *testing);
```

Comment: `explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr, const int & testing);` you need to supply the default value from right to left. https://www.quora.com/Why-are-default-arguments-assigned-from-right-to-left-in-C++

Comment: What is the purpose for the testing parameter? Why is it pass by reference for a single integer? Is there some logical default value for this parameter?

Comment: I want to pass data to Dialog.ui from mainwindow.cpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is invalid:

```
Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr, const int & testing);
```

because default values must be always after non ones.... so your integer parameter "testing" can not be placed after parent.

do set a default value for he integer:

```
Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr, const int & testing = 0);
```

or change its order in the constructor

```
Dialog(const int & testing, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
```